# I want make a swipe menu in android but I cant push my layout out of screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I want make a swipe menu in android but I can't push my layout out of screen.
I tried animating and translationX none worked.

[image: This is what I want to make 1]

[image: This is what I want to make 2]

this is the whole menu I wrote for menu  but when I animate the buttons seem to work at the place the were before not where they are animated to, i fixed that by using margin but when I use that it cuts out the remaining of layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu_BTNs"
        android:layout_marginRight="-2dp"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/menu_coinPLusBTN"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/coin_plus" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/menu_pointsBTN"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/points" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/menu_settingsBTN"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/settings" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@drawable/menu"
        android:layout_width="342dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show what you have tried till now.

Comment: I added my code you can check it out now